# Issue with Custom Field Type not rendering in Shell

Tags: custom-field

I created a custom Field in `/sitecore/system/Field types/User Defined`, called `Role Selector`. It inherits from a class called `MultilistExBase` (which I have brought into the project thanks to [this post](http://sitecoreblog.bltogspot.com/2012_04_01_archive.html)) which itself extends `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.MultilistEx`.  As soon as I create the field in the `Core`, that new field shows up in the list of available fields. But when I go to actually set the field on an instance of said template, it displays a textbox instead of a `Multilist`, with no errors.  I have tried both defining the `Assembly/Class` for the field type and `controlPrefix:RoleSelector` with no success.  I have also combed through the logs and found nothing as well.  This project instance is Sitecore 8.0 (rev. 151127).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After copying `/sitecore/system/Field types/List Types/Multilist` from `List Type` to the `/sitecore/system/Field types/User Defined` and renaming, I went over to `Master`, updated the template to the newly copied `Multilist` field type.  It still did not work, only showing a basic textbox, no error on screen or in the logs.  That then led me to check the `/sitecore/system/Field types/User Defined` folder, only to find it was not a `Common/Folder` template type at all, but instead a `/sitecore/templates/System/Node` template type.  I then changed the template type in the `Configure` tab on `User Defined` to `Common/Folder` in `Core`, went back over to `Master` and the field started working immediately.  I can only assume at this point that `User Defined` item was cast as a `Node` due to some template type mismatch when I imported it from an 8.1 Sitecore instance.  I am somewhat curious as to why it failed so silently, and why the field type did indeed show up in the list, but the control rendering did not as much as even hit a breakpoint.

**Summary**: After verifying your custom field is indeed set up correctly (`Assembly/Class` or `controlPrefix:ControlClass`) and are *still* having issues with it rendering at all, verify that the parent `Folder` type is indeed a `Common/Folder`.